# Replace index column in dataframe

Tags: r, visualization, d3heatmap

I’m trying to do a heatmap with a dataset using "d3heatmap".

I have a dataframe whose first column contains the name of soccer players. However, I'm getting the following error because that column in not numeric.

> Error in rowMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm) : 'x' must be numeric"

```
+----------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+
| Index column         | Player             | Minutes | Goals |
+----------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+
| 1                    |             Robert | 1234    | 10    |
| 2                    |             John   | 1253    | 15    |
| 3                    |             Mark   | 112     | 1     |
+----------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+
```

How could I replace the index column of a data frame with my first column (player)?

Ideal situation

```
+--------------------+---------+-------+
| Player             | Minutes | Goals |
+--------------------+---------+-------+
|             Robert | 1234    | 10    |
|             John   | 1253    | 15    |
|             Mark   | 112     | 1     |
+--------------------+---------+-------+
```

I'm trying to search for similar questions but I haven't got the answer.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance. Much appreciated.

Thanks,
Juanma

Comment: Try out this example. `dat <- data.frame(a=letters[1:5], val=rnorm(5))` some toy data.frame. Then `dat2 <- as.data.frame(dat[-1], row.names=as.character(dat[,1]))`.

Comment: This is great.  Thanks for sending the note. It really works for my dataset. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want `dat2` or `dat3` below. In fact, I'm not sure that `Index column` is a column in your original `data.frame`, I will assume that it is.

```
dat <- data.frame(
        index = 1:3,
        Player = c("Robert", "John", "Mark"),
        Minutes = c(1234, 1253, 112),
        Goals = c(10, 15, 1)
    )

dat
dat2 <- dat[, -1]
dat2
  Player Minutes Goals
1 Robert    1234    10
2   John    1253    15
3   Mark     112     1
```

In the next case, `dat3`, I've eliminated the column `Player` and transformed its values in the row names.

```
dat3 <- dat[, -(1:2)]
rownames(dat3) <- dat$Player
dat3
       Minutes Goals
Robert    1234    10
John      1253    15
Mark       112     1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it really works for me. Yes, it's the second example what I needed.

Comment: Should dat3 <- dat[, -(1:2)] be dat3 <- dat[, -1] if we want to remove just the first column?

Comment: @HendraBunyamin Yes, that is even the previous case, `dat2`.